# Frame background color disappears when a new widget is assigned to it (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from  tkinter import *

mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.geometry("800x700")
listaFrame = Frame(mainWindow, background ='#00ff00', height = 300 , width = 300)
listaFrame.grid(row= 0 , column =0)
label = Label(listaFrame,text = "Why is the Background color of the frame removed")
label.pack()

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

With out the label , the window is a 800x700 pixel window with a 300x300 pixel Green frame, but when the label is assigned to the frame, the label gets displayed and the the frame(background color and size) becomes hidden.
How can i make it that the frame(size and background) doesn't disappear?
thanks in advance (kinda new to tkinter/coding)

Comment: A Frame with contents will normally ignore its `height` and `width` options, instead adjusting its size to fit the contents.  So your Frame still has its green background, however it's entirely covered by the Label.  `listaFrame.pack_propagate(0)` would turn off this behavior.

Comment: thank you so much , i thought that it was something in my code that had given that effect to the frame.<3